# How to Access variables of a function that is inside a class from outside the class in python3

Tags: python-3.x

This is a sample code in python3.7

`code`

```
class MyClass(object):
    def xxx(self):
        self.a = 10
        self.b = 15
        self.c = 20

    def yyy(self):
        self.xxx()
        print(self.a)
        print(self.b)

#Create an instance of the class
obj = MyClass()

obj.yyy() #this will print value of a and b
```

`code`

I want the value of a and b outside the  class that inside the function xxx()
for eg

```
obj = MyClass()
x = obj.xxx()
print(x.a)
print(x.b)
```

but this gives error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'

Comment: If you want to do as you write then create new variables as class attributes then assign values of these variables to them then print out them. Because now a and b are local variables they cant outsource. Their scope is with in the method.

Comment: Thanks @AdamStrauss for your idea, but is there any way rather than creating new class attribute and assigning these values to them? I just want those values of variables outside the class.

Comment: Why not just `print(obj.a)` and `print(obj.b)` since these are not local variables but are instance variables?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This will help you out. That is why your case is not possible.